# Run shell scripts through a website

Tags: shell, scripting, html

I have been reading and searching on what is the **best** way to run my shell scripts through a website.

My goals are as follows:

- Browse a folder
- Select folder or contents
- onclick will run script
- Files will be modified and output results inside a `.txt` file

I have searched mostly for [CGI](http://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20cgi%20a%20shell%20script%20in%20a%20website&oq=how%20to%20cgi%20a%20shell%20script%20in%20a%20website&sugexp=chrome,mod=2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but I know there maybe other alternatives.  Also, I am using a Linux hosting server from a 3rd party company.

I did run across these helpful sites for others to read:
[CGI Security](http://www.yossman.net/support/cgisecurity.html) & [YoLinux](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialCgiShellScript.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[shbot](https://github.com/geirha/shbot) is a very nice IRC bot used for the [#bash Freenode channel](http://webchat.freenode.net/?randomnick=1&channels=bash&prompt=1&uio=d4). You can ask it to run Bash code for you:

```
/privmsg shbot echo test
```

It should be relatively easy to adapt this to work with a static web page.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to do such thing, but if I really needed it I would, probably, modify [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html) to generate special links for `*.sh` files, pointing to CGI script which does the job.